# Enviar foto para o banco atráves do onChange no React?

Tags: react

Estou convertendo a foto para base64 e exibindo no console, mas o valor no useState não atualiza de imediato. Ele mostra apenas a partir segunda tentativa de upload da foto.

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react';

const Portfolio = () => {

  const[fotoPortifolio, setFotoPortifolio] = useState({
        foto: ""
    })

   function handleFoto(e){
  
      var file = e.target.files[0],
       reader = new FileReader();
           
      reader.onloadend = function () {
       var b64 = reader.result.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, '');
        setFotoPortifolio({...fotoPortifolio,
         foto:  b64
        })};
           
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    addFoto()
}


   function addFoto() {    
  
        console.log(fotoPortifolio)

    }

  
  return (
        <>

        <input  name="foto" onChange={handleFoto} type='file' accept="image/png, image/jpeg"/>
               </>

    )
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método **useState** é  assíncrono o que quer dizer que ele leva um tempo para executar e quando você dá o console.log na variável **fotoPortifolio** ela ainda não está pronta com o valor.

O recomendado para verificar o valor de um estado sempre que ele for alterado é utilizar o **useEffect** que é  também um hook do React.

Adicione no seu código esse hook:

useEffect(() => {
console.log(fotoPortifolio);
}, [fotoPortifolio])

Assim toda vez que o valor de **fotoPortfolio** for alterado, o hook useEffect vai ser chamado.

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Obrigada, uma pergunta useEffect permite verificar apenas uma variavel exemplo:           useEffect(() => {console.log(`${fotoPortfolio} e ${props.id} `); } [fotoPortifolio])

Comment: O hook **useEffect** vai executar SEMPRE  que  as suas dependências forem atualizadas. As dependências são o que vc passa como parâmetro no array de dependências dele. No nosso exemplo a dependência é  **fotoPortfolio** então sempre que essa variável for atualizada o useEffect vai executar. Se você achar que minha resposta te ajudou a resolver/entender seu problema marca como resposta por favor.  Obrigado